# How can do a performance friendly version of this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey guys i'm new to RoR and ruby in general.

In this project i am working at the moment i'm showing 4 images of a vehicle that were previously uploaded by users.

In my class 'Vehicle' i have a singleton method **- that returns an array with urls for attached images of a vehicle object -** which i call like this `Vehicle.vehicle_images(@vehicle.id)`. I'd like to make this method look more performatic and less hard-coded.

*my vehicle class:*

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vehicles_attachment, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :vehicles_attachment_imagem, -> { where({ type_attachment: 'imagem' }) }, class_name: 'VehiclesAttachment', dependent: :destroy

   def self.vehicle_images(vehicle_id)
     if vehicle_id
       images = VehiclesAttachment.where({ vehicle_id: vehicle_id, type_attachment: :imagem })
       urls = []
       if !images.nil? && !images.empty?
         count = 0
         images.each do |img|
           urls << if img.attachment.file?
                     "https:#{img.attachment.url(:regular)}"
                   else
                     4.times do
urls << ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('viatura.jpg', digest: false).to_s
                     end
                   end
          count += 1
         end
         if count < 4
           (4 - count).times do
             urls << ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('viatura.jpg', digest: false).to_s
           end
         end
       else
         4.times do
           urls << ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('viatura.jpg', digest: false).to_s
         end
       end
     else
       4.times do
         urls << ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('viatura.jpg', digest: false).to_s
       end
     end
     urls
   end
end
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you really have to deal with the case that there is no `vehicle_id`? Is it really necessary to return the `viatura.jpg`? Or is this something you could handle in the view, for example with a background image that is only visible when a slot is not filled with a real image? Why the min of 4 images? What if there are more than 4 images?

Comment: There's a lot happening here! I think just breaking it up into smaller methods would help. Would you be able to describe in words the goal of this method?

Comment: i think maybe there will be cases where vehicle_id could be empty even if passed or is this redundant?

Comment: @spickermann this method is a work-around to show attached imgs of a vehicle record, like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/fheUWkV), what could i do in the view?, like if vehicle_images returns an empty array should show an sample image???

Comment: @JakeWorth I call this method on a api that send me a json with all the vehicles info, then use the json to populate a table with the retrieved records. All this method do is search all 4 images on Model 'VehicleAttachments' (front view, back view, and side views of a vehicle, i.e: A car, A Truck or A Bus) through relation with a single Vehicle record. you can see a sample here [link](https://imgur.com/a/fheUWkV)

Comment: @ElissonG.M.Silva I think your path is to write a unit test describing all of your desired behavior, and then look for redundant/unreachable code. Nested if/else's and loops inside of loops are tough to reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step it could be simplified to this:

```
def self.vehicle_images(vehicle_id)
  blank_image_url = ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('viatura.jpg', digest: false).to_s

  urls = []

  if vehicle_id
    VehiclesAttachment.where(vehicle_id: vehicle_id, type_attachment: :imagem).each do |image|
      urls << img.attachment.file? ? "https:#{img.attachment.url(:regular)}" : blank_image_url
    end
  end

  urls << blank_image_url while urls.size < 4

  urls
end
```

But this is just a first step. The next steps could be:

- Determine if you have to deal with blank `vehicle_id`. If not then an instance method on a vehicle would be better than a class method. And you would be able to use the defined association instead of the `where` on the class.
- I would investigate if it is really possible that you sometimes get only some images returned and really have to fill in the dummy image between them. Or if it would be enough to only fill in dummy images at the end if there are less than 4. That would simplify the method further.
- I wonder if you sometimes have to deal with more than 4 images? Your code currently doesn't handle that.
- Perhaps you could add variations to ensure that there are always exactly the four images?

Comment: Thank you guys, @spickermann example did the job reducing the cyclomatic complexity of this method. edit: there was some typos and an issue with the ternary operator block